# Function to calculate average linkage distance between two groups of points

Tags: r

In `hclust`, one can specify `method = "average"` to use average linkage in clustering.

My situation is that I have two *fixed* clusters, and I want to calculate the average linkage between these two clusters.

Is there a function to do this in R? The `hclust` seems to use Fortran code to do this.

Sample data:

```
structure(list(lon = c(106.0081819, 106.0621591, 106.0787142, 
105.9581624, 105.9982149, 105.9455287, 106.0726373, 106.12575, 
106.1110501, 106.060344, 106.0635147, 105.9575665, 105.9494248, 
106.0475363, 105.9564829, 105.9964291, 106.1037006, 105.9964291, 
106.1639749, 106.1110501), lat = c(21.1400879, 21.1766814, 21.1738006, 
21.202957, 21.1244525, 21.1101074, 21.1861204, 21.163438, 21.121444, 
21.169068, 21.1815923, 21.1085185, 21.0994022, 21.1688445, 21.1158848, 
21.1122605, 21.1988765, 21.1122605, 21.0178933, 21.121444), group = c("domestic", 
"foreign", "domestic", "domestic", "foreign", "domestic", "domestic", 
"foreign", "domestic", "domestic", "domestic", "domestic", "domestic", 
"domestic", "foreign", "domestic", "domestic", "foreign", "domestic", 
"domestic")), .Names = c("lon", "lat", "group"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
d <- dist(df[, 1:2]) 
idx <- as.matrix(expand.grid(which(df$group=="domestic"), which(df$group=="foreign"))) 
mean(as.matrix(d)[idx])
# [1] 0.09028491
```

if the average linkage is the average distance (here: euclidean) between each point in cluster 1 and each point in cluster 2.

Comment: I was coming up with the same solution, albeit `as.matrix(d)[which(df$group=="domestic"), which(df$group=="foreign")]` instead. Is this the same as doing `expand.grid`?

Comment: Should be. Sometimes I think too complicated. :->